# Permanent java objects

Tags: java, object, permanent

I was wondering (there has to be an easy solution) if there is a way to make a number of objects, and use them in other classes and objects from those classes, without having to update them (in Java). An example:

Class A, B and C make objects a b and c. 
Then I have class D, which makes object d. 
Now I want to use d in a, change it, use d in b, change it there and use d in c and still have all the changes from a and b. 
I know it's possible with using d as an argument in the functions, and returning d, but that is not useful in the program I'm making at the moment.

Any help?

Ok, My example in code:

```
public class A {
   D d = new D ();
   A(D dObject){
     this.d = dObject;
   }
   public void add () {
     DObject.add(5);
   }
}

public class B {
   D d = new D ();
   B(D dObject){
     this.d = dObject;
   }
   public void add () {
     DObject.add(5);
   }
}

public class C {
   D d = new D ();
   C(D dObject){
     this.d = dObject;
   }
   public void add () {
     DObject.add(5);
   }
}
public class D {
   public int x=0;
   public void add (int y){
      x +=y;
   }
}

// in main class:
D d = new D();
A a = new A(d);
B b = new B(d);
C c = new C(d);

a.add();
b.add();
c.add();

// d.x should give 15 now.
```

Comment: D makes d??.. You need to rephrase your question better.

Comment: This is the most complicated question I think I've ever read.  Please try to rephrase this into something that makes sense...toooo many things to keep track of....

Comment: Also, that would require 3 different instances of "d" or some sort of versioning engine...

Comment: Sound like you're looking for a global variable. These tend to be a bad idea

Comment: This sounds like a very BAD idea, and goes against just about anything anyone has ever written about object oriented programming. Why can't you pass it as an argument? What do these objects / classes do? Why can't they be static methods?

Comment: I updated, see what you think now. I do NOT want to update, that's what I want to stop doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand right - the code you posted does exactly what you say (`d.x` is 15), if you correct the syntax errors.

Here is a version that should work:

```
public class A {
   D d;
   A(D dObject){
     this.d = dObject;
   }
   public void add () {
     d.add(5);
   }
}

public class B {
   D d;
   B(D dObject){
     this.d = dObject;
   }
   public void add () {
     d.add(5);
   }
}

public class C {
   D d;
   C(D dObject){
     this.d = dObject;
   }
   public void add () {
     d.add(5);
   }
}
public class D {
   public int x=0;
   public void add (int y){
      x +=y;
   }
}

// in main class:
D d = new D();
A a = new A(d);
B b = new B(d);
C c = new C(d);

a.add();
b.add();
c.add();

// d.x should give 15 now.
```

If you want `d` to stay the same instead of changing (e.g. `d.x == 0` at the end), you can do one of these:

- make clones of the parameter `dObject` in the constructor of A, B, C, so each has its own `D` object.
- make `D` immutable and let its `add` method instead return a new `D` object. The `add` method of `A`, `B`, `C` would then have the implementation `d = d.add(5);`.

Comment: Thanks, this is not the kind of code I had I mind, but I will definately try this.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)
It only works if you want a single instance of class D, but you can create a singleton to store references of other objects. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I think you mean [Immutable Objects](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) based on your description.

Comment: Did he not mention, a changes b, c changes b... Even tho the question is cryptic, the object being mutable is obvious.